# symfony database lock whith session

Tags: php, symfony, session, doctrine, locking

I try to create a php based system for multiple users. I am using Symfony2 as a framework. Data ist stored in a MySQL Database.

To allow different users to work with the system simulaniously I want to lock database entries. As far as I know doctrine supports optimistic and pessimistic locking. My idea was to lock an entry (respectively tho whole object or row) pessimistic when a user opens a site for editing this entry. It should stays locked till he finishes editing it or he aborts it ... so till he goes to another site.

To avoid a deadlock I thought about including a timer which frees the antry after a certain time of inactivity (plus a popup message asking the user if he is still working on it).

I guess this could be done with session management. But to be honest I have no idea how. I hope you could give me some input about this.

Best regards
SpiGAndromeda

Comment: I don't think I'd go down that path, it sounds painful and likely to cause problems. Why not use an external shared data key store like memcache or something to lock the record id by some key/user while the record is being edited? Then if someone tries to access that document while another user is editing if you can display that it is locked. That way you're not potentially deadlocking your database. You could refresh the lock with some kind of ajax or similar (and give it a reasonable timeout for if the user goes AFK etc). Just a thought on an alternative approach.

Comment: Ok. I hope I understand that the rigth way ... I should use memchache to store the id of the entry which is edited (with a certain expire time). And every time somebdody opens an editing page i check wether the key of this entry exists in memchache?

Comment: Yup, something like that. While the user has the record open you could use some sort of js/ajax functionality to keep the key expiry fresh. You could get fancier and only refresh the expiry from input events or similar. It's a general approach, there's a lot of ways you can implement it.